# Google sheets formula to sequence a list of dates and stepping by year

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of non working days for Mexico as follows:

```
01-Jan-22
06-Feb-22
20-Mar-22
14-Apr-22
01-May-22
16-Sep-22
20-Nov-22
01-Dec-22
12-Dec-22
25-Dec-22
```

I need a formula to sequence this list, the step should be by year

so this year I get all the list for 2022 and also for 2023, and next year to automatically have also the same dates for 2024 and so on for every year

would be great to have all the dates inside the formula and not from any referenced list

any help on this please?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach you can try out:

```
=let(Σ,A1:A10,
 reduce(Σ,sequence(datedif(index(Σ,1,1),today(),"Y")),lambda(a,c,{a;index(edate(Σ,12*c))})))
```

- you can replace the `A1:A10` part with the dates list directly if that's how you need the end line formula

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula. Change the "2" after SEQUENCE to select how many years you want the dates to expand; and if you need add more dates in between the curly brackets with quotation marks:

```
=REDUCE("Holidays",SEQUENCE(2,1,0),LAMBDA(h,s,{h;SCAN(,
{"01-Jan-22";"06-Feb-22";"20-Mar-22";"14-Apr-22";"01-May-22";"16-Sep-22";"20-Nov-22";"01-Dec-22";"12-Dec-22";"25-Dec-22"},
LAMBDA(a,v,EDATE(DATEVALUE(v),12*s)))}))
```

[image]

As you see if I put `SEQUENCE(3.....` it continues into year 2024:

[image]